# Check if date string is current date

Tags: php

i'm scraping a lot dates which i would like to check wether they are from today.

so something like

```
if ("Apr 9, 2015 18:45" ==  date('Y-m-d ))
```

How can i check if a string date like

```
 Apr 9, 2015 18:45
```

is today?

list of dates i'm checking

```
 Apr 9, 2015 23:40
 Apr 9, 2015 18:45
 Apr 9, 2015 14:18
 Apr 9, 2015 13:23
 Apr 9, 2015 12:24
 Apr 9, 2015 11:00
 Apr 8, 2015 21:15
 Apr 8, 2015 21:15
 Apr 8, 2015 19:35
 Apr 8, 2015 18:54
 Apr 8, 2015 17:09
 Apr 8, 2015 16:41
 Apr 8, 2015 16:30
 Apr 8, 2015 15:55
 Apr 8, 2015 14:15
 Apr 8, 2015 12:38
 Apr 8, 2015 12:12
 Apr 7, 2015 22:30
 Apr 7, 2015 22:15
 Apr 7, 2015 18:26
```

loop snippet

```
foreach($gosu->find("//table[@class='simple gamelist medium']/tbody/tr") as $gosu_element) {



    $gosu_date = mysql_real_escape_string($gosu_element->find("/td[@class='live-in']", 0));
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($gosu_date)) ==  date('Y-m-d')){
        echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($gosu_date)) . "<br>"; 
    }


}
```

var_dump output:

```
string(0) "" string(44) "Apr 9, 2015 23:40" string(44) "Apr 9, 2015 18:45"   string(44) "Apr 9, 2015 14:18" string(44) "Apr 9, 2015 13:23" string(44) "Apr 9, 2015 12:24" string(44) "Apr 9, 2015 11:00" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 21:15" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 21:15" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 19:35" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 18:54" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 17:09" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 16:41" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 16:30" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 15:55" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 14:15" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 12:38" string(44) "Apr 8, 2015 12:12" string(44) "Apr 7, 2015 22:30" string(44) "Apr 7, 2015 22:15" string(44) "Apr 7, 2015 18:26"
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` should not be needed unless posting to a MySQL Database. Also as was said `string(44)` means there is 44 characters of string. Try `print_r()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strtotime() is pretty handy:

```
if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Apr 9, 2015 18:45")) ==  date('Y-m-d')){
```

This will result in similar strings. Entered will be compared to now `"2015-04-09" == "2015-04-09"`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I would do something like:

```
<?php
$dates = array(
  "Apr 9, 2015 23:40",
  "Apr 8, 2015 18:45",
  "Apr 7, 2015 14:18"
);
$num_true = 0;
$today = date('Y-m-d');

for($i=0;$i<=count($dates);$i++){
  if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dates[$i])) != $today){
    unset($dates[$i]);
  }
}
// Array only has dates that are equal to today.

echo "There are " . count($dates) . " dates that match today:\r\n";
foreach($dates as $day){
  echo "$day\r\n";
}
?>
```

Edit: Bad logic in FOR statement.

Comment: sry but strtotime returns 1970-01-01

Comment: Just tested the following code:
`$now = date('Y-m-d');
$opt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Apr 9, 2015 18:36"));

if($now == $opt){
        echo "$now == $opt";
} else {
        echo "$now != $opt";
}`
Works as expected.

Comment: I've added a list of dates i'm looping through and in strtotime they all return 1970-01-01

Comment: Please add your current Code snippet.

Comment: @PeterPik Twisty's answer is correct and works perfectly fine. You have to update your question with your **full** and **real** code how you use it now

Comment: I've added it now. $gosu_date is equal to the date string

Comment: @PeterPik Do `var_dump($gosu_date);` and show us the **exact** output which you get. (just from one or two dates)

Comment: Updated it! look question

Comment: @PeterPik Look at this output in the **source code**! And post the output from the source code (Do you see the `string(44)` they don't match the strings which you see)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) it as you want to compare it, like this:

```
if ((new DateTime("Apr 9, 2015 18:45"))->format("Y-m-d") ==  date("Y-m-d"))
```

Comment: Why not `if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Apr 9, 2015 18:45")) == date("Y-m-d"))`

Comment: @Twisty Since OP only wants to compare if year, month and day is the same. So if you take the timestamp you compare also hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )` strtotime() will provide the timestamp; thus resulting strings will be comparable.

Comment: @Twisty OP only wants to know if the year month AND the day is the same! So the hours and so on are irrelevant. Means if you use the timestamp where the seconds and so on also counts you do a different comparison

Comment: @Twisty And now we have the same answer +/- only that I'm used to `DateTime` since it's very flexible.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what OP was driving for the first go around. I would agree our methods result in true (for today of course :) )

Comment: @Twisty Same for me. I also thought the same until I realized that he wants to ignore hours and so on! (But here only for this `DateTime` might be a bit of an overhead)

Comment: It's the difference of a few more characters. I have found `strtotime()` to be more forgiving. So if the DateTime string is "april 9th 2015" or "04-09-15", it will still parse it into a timestamp. I don't recall how forgiving the DateTime constructor is with formats.